# has ngComponentRouter been released as part of 1.5.5 or is it still in beta?

Tags: angularjs

In bower the angular-component-router package is only at 0.2.1.  Is that the right router for angular 1.5.5?  Seems weird that the documentation would point to this for Angular 1 if it's not RTM yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of component router for Angular 1 is depreciated. They are considering to backport Angular 2 component router.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

> Deprecation Notice: In an effort to keep synchronized with router
>   changes in Angular 2, this implementation of the Component Router
>   (ngComponentRouter module) has been deprecated and will not receive
>   further updates. We are investigating backporting the Angular 2 Router
>   to Angular 1, but alternatively, use the ngRoute module or community
>   developed projects (e.g. ui-router).

Comment: Thanks for that mate.